# Pivot table with count if

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pivot-table

I want to count if the number is higher than 0.1 and then group them by month-year to see which month-year has the most days with more than 0.1 variations.

I have a df like these with daily data but only showing month-year index.

[image]

```
table = df.pivot_table(df, columns=['btc','bnb','eth','xmr','xrp'], aggfunc=df[df > 0.1].count())

print(table)
```

Why not working?

The result needs to be something like this

[image: The result will be something like this]

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want to `count` only the values which are greater than `0.1` in all coulmns per `month-year`?

Comment: yes! and then show a data frame where the index is groupby month-year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `stack` the dataframe then compare the stacked frame with `0.1` to create a booolean mask then take `sum` on `level=0` to count the values which are greater than `0.1` per `month-year`:

```
df.stack().gt(0.1).sum(level=0)
```

Alternate approach:

```
df[df > 0.1].stack().count(level=0)
```

EDIT: If you want to count the values which are greater than `0.1` in each of the column per `month-year`:

```
df.gt(0.1).sum(level=0)
```

Comment: Amazing help! Is that but i also need the columns 'btc','bnb','eth','xmr','xrp' .
Thats why I was trying to use pivot_table or even grouby fucntions

Comment: @TiagoEmanuelPratas Can you please update the question with your desired output(just one or two rows maybe) so that it can be easier to visualize what you want?

Comment: IIUC I think you need `df.gt(0.1).sum(level=0)`?